# Proof verification: $E(g(X)) = \int_a^{\infty} g'(t)(1 - F_X(t)) dt + g(a)$ if $P(X\ge a)=1$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ be a probability space, $X: \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb R$ a random variable with $X \ge a$ almost everywhere and $a \in \Bbb R \cup \{-\infty\}.$ Furthermore, let $g: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function.
>
> Then
>
> $$E(g(X)) = \int_a^{\infty} g'(t)(1 - F_X(t)) dt + g(a),$$
>
> with $E(g(X))$ being the expected value of $g(X)$ and $F_X$ being the distribution function.

The proof starts like this:

$$E(g(X)) = \int_a^{\infty} g(t) \ dP_X(t) = \int_a^{\infty} \left(\int_a^{\infty} g'(s) \ dP_X(t) \ 1_{(s \le t)} (s) ds + g(a)\right) \  dP_X(t),$$

and this is where I already lost sight. $1_{(s \le t)}$ denotes the indicator function. I don't see how he is actually applying Fubini here, and it confuses me how he worked with the derivative of $g$ at this point. Can anybody explain to me how to make a sense out of this last equation?

Comment: The idea is that, for every $t\geqslant a$, $$g(t)=g(a)+\int_a^tg'(s)ds=g(a)+\int_a^\infty g'(s)1_{(s\leqslant t)}ds$$ hence the RHS you should have written in your question is $$\int_a^\infty\left(g(a)+\int_a^\infty g'(s)1_{(s\leqslant t)}ds\right)dP_X(t)$$ and now, Fubini yields that this is also $$g(a)\int_a^\infty dP_X(t)+\int_a^\infty g'(s)\left(\int_a^\infty 1_{(s\leqslant t)}dP_X(t)\right)ds$$ which is also, by definition of $P_X$, $$g(a)P(X\geqslant a)+\int_a^\infty g'(s)\left(\int_s^\infty dP_X(t)\right)ds=g(a)P(X\geqslant a)+\int_a^\infty g'(s)P(X>s)ds$$

Comment: ... and, since $P(X\geqslant a)=1$ and $P(X>s)=1-F_X(s)$, you are done.

Comment: Thanks! I thought a while about it, but one thing I don't understand is this step: $\int_a^{\infty} 1_{(s \le t)} dP_X(t) = \int_s^{\infty} dP_X(t)$. Wouldn't it be necessary to know that $a \le s \le t$ to conclude this? And what is the input of $1_{(s \le t)}$ on the right side of the equality anyway? It made sense to me when we integrated with respect to $s$ before, but not now.

Comment: In this integral, $s\geqslant a$ anyway hence $t\geqslant s\geqslant a$ if and only if $t\geqslant s$.

Comment: Ah, sure, in the first line, we can see that $s \in [a, t]$, that makes sense then, thanks!